# How to add user coins to existing coins in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, sharedpreferences

I´m developing a game in Kotlin. My goal is that every time the user presses a specific button he gets 20 coins added to his existing coins. Afterward, the coin number should be saved with shared preferences.

Shared preferences:

```
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SP_INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
var coins = preferenceFile.getInt("COINS", 0)
```

Here is the layout of the text view which displays the coin number:

```
//Coin Label
<TextView android:id="@+id/coinlabel"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="60dp"

          android:textSize="40sp"
          android:textColor="@color/coinlabel"
          android:textAlignment="textStart"

          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          />
```

I tried to add 20 coins to the existing coins but it didn´t work like I wanted it to.

```
var coins = Int

button.setOnClickListener {

        coins = 20 + coins  //The plus symbol may be used wrong here
        editor.putInt("COINS",coins)
        editor.apply()  //Here I want to save the coins number to shared-preferences
        coinlabel.setText(Integer.toString(coins))

        println(coins)
    }
```

The entire class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SP_INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
var coins = sharedPreferences.getInt("COINS", 0)

var pressed: Boolean? = false
var audioon = true


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    supportActionBar?.hide()
    this.getWindow()
        .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)


  soundon.setOnClickListener{

        audioon = false

        editor.putBoolean("AUDIOON", audioon)
        editor.apply()
     }

    soundoff.setOnClickListener {

        audioon = true

        editor.putBoolean("AUDIOON", audioon)
        editor.apply()
    }

  button.setOnClickListener {

        coins += 20
        coinlabel.setText(Integer.toString(coins))
        editor.putInt("COINS",coins)
        editor.apply()
        println(coins)
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: How do you want it to work?

Comment: I said at the top of my question what I want to achieve. @TaseerAhmad

Comment: You want to add coins to existing coins in the shared peferences, but what you are doing is actually removing previously stored coins and adding new to it? Is this what is happening?

Comment: I don´t want to remove previously stored coins. How can I prevent that from happening? @TaseerAhmad

Comment: What is `preferenceFile`?

Comment: I added the whole class. @Tenfour04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize these parameters that depend on Context outside the Activity lifecycle functions, because the Context is not fully available when the Activity class is first instantiated:

```
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SP_INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
var coins = sharedPreferences.getInt("COINS", 0)
```

Instead, you can make them `var lateinit` and instantiate them in `onCreate` like this:

```
lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor
var coins = 0

//...

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SP_INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    coins = sharedPreferences.getInt("COINS", 0)
    //...
}
```

Comment: what can I do about the error(first two lines of lateinit): property getter or setter expected

Comment: Oops, sorry! The word `lateinit` has to come before `var`. I fixed it above.